# picture returning to app is sideways

Tags: android, xml

making a simple app, the problem I am having now is that when im using an intent to launch the camera app to take a picture, the app is supposed to take the picture and overwrite the imageview which was for the background image. What its doing is bring the freshly taken picture and displaying it sideways.

this is my main java file:

```
package com.example.piktuur;
import java.io.File;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Bitmap;
import android.graphics.BitmapFactory;
import android.net.Uri;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.os.Environment;
import android.provider.MediaStore;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.ImageView;
import android.widget.SeekBar;


public class PiktuurMain extends Activity {

    private Uri outputFileUri;
    private static int TAKE_PICTURE = 1;
    private ImageView image;
    private SeekBar adjust;
    public int height, width;
    public boolean proceede;
    public File file;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.piktuur_main);
        image = (ImageView) findViewById(R.id.imageView1);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.piktuur_main, menu);
        return true;
    }

    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
        if (requestCode == TAKE_PICTURE && resultCode == RESULT_OK) {
            BitmapFactory.Options options = new BitmapFactory.Options();
            String file = Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory() + "/image.png";
            Bitmap bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(file, options);
            image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
        }
    }

    public void cameraClicked(View V){

        Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ACTION_IMAGE_CAPTURE);
        File file = new File(Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory(), "image.png");
        outputFileUri = Uri.fromFile(file);
        intent.putExtra(MediaStore.EXTRA_OUTPUT, outputFileUri);
        startActivityForResult(intent, TAKE_PICTURE);

    }

    public void shareClicked(View V){
        Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SEND);
        intent.setType("text/plain");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_EMAIL, "stephen.w.protzman@gmail.com");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_SUBJECT, "Piktuur");
        intent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_TEXT, "Here is a picture for you!");
        startActivity(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Send Email"));

    }
}
```

and here is the main xml with the imageview in it:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context=".PiktuurMain" >

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/imageView1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:scaleType="fitXY"
        android:src="@drawable/pic" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="5dp" >

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/takepic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:onClick="cameraClicked"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_camera" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/editpic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_marginLeft="15dp"
            android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_edit" />

        <ImageButton
            android:id="@+id/sharepic"
            android:layout_width="0dp"
            android:layout_height="fill_parent"
            android:layout_weight="1"
            android:background="@drawable/round"
            android:onClick="shareClicked"
            android:src="@android:drawable/ic_menu_share" />
    </LinearLayout>

    <SeekBar
        android:id="@+id/seekBar1"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_above="@+id/linearLayout1"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I have zero ideas why this is happening any clue?

Answer (score 0):

> try this

```
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
        {
            super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
            if (resultCode == RESULT_OK)
            {
                Uri imageUri = data.getData();
                Bitmap bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(this.getContentResolver(), imageUri);
                image.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
            }
        }
```

Comment: meh, causes the application to break while returning the image